# Javascript Local Variables Accessible from Methods After Instantiation?

Tags: javascript, variables, object, scope, instantiation

So I'm brushing up on my vanilla Javascript, specifically for animation, and I came across a tutorial with the following code:

```
function sprite(options){

        var spr = {},
            frameIndex = 0,
            tickCount = 0,
            ticksPerFrame = options.ticksPerFrame || 0,
            numberOfFrames = options.numberOfFrames || 1;

        spr.context = options.context;
        spr.width = options.width;
        spr.height = options.height;
        spr.image = options.image;
        spr.loop = options.loop;

        spr.render = function(){
            console.log("render");
            //console.log("height: ", spr.height);
            //console.log("width: ", spr.width);
            //console.log("context: ", spr.context);
            //console.log("image: ", spr.image);

            // Clear Canvas
            spr.context.clearRect(0, 0, spr.width, spr.height);

            // Draw animation
            spr.context.drawImage(
                spr.image,
                frameIndex * spr.width / numberOfFrames,
                0,
                spr.width / numberOfFrames,
                spr.height,
                0,
                0,
                spr.width / numberOfFrames,
                spr.height
            );
        };

        spr.update = function(){
            tickCount += 1;

            if (tickCount > ticksPerFrame){
                tickCount = 0;

                if (frameIndex < numberOfFrames - 1){
                    frameIndex += 1;
                } else if (spr.loop) {
                    frameIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        };

        return spr;
    }
```

I understand all of the logic and everything, but how are

- `frameIndex`
- `tickCount`
- `ticksPerFrame`
- `numberOfFrames`

accessible from the `render()` and `update()` methods after `spr` has been returned? As far as I can tell, they're local functions to the `sprite` function and shouldn't be accessible after instantiation.

Comment: [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 2):

They *are* local to the `sprite` function.

The other functions you mention are defined inside the `sprite` function and so have access to any variables that are in its scope.

They continue to be available after the `sprite` function has finished because they have been returned. This is called *a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)*.

Comment: So if you instantiate other objects, do they all draw from the same variables or will they have their own copies just as if they had been defined as `spr.varname`?